# I have two confusion in sylow theorem formula . True/false

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I have   two  confusion in sylow  theorem formula

$1.$Order of a $n$ sylow subgroup in $GL_n (\mathbb{F_p})= \frac{\prod_ {i=0}^{n-1} (p^n -p^i)}{(p-1)^n p^{\frac {n(n-1)}{2}}}$

$2.$ Order of a $q-$sylow subgroups in $GL_n (\mathbb{F_p})=$the highest power of $q$ dividing  $\prod_ {i=0}^{n-1} (p^n -p^i)$

Edits : Note  : Here  $n$ is  prime number for  cases $1$

Is  the  given  above formula is true /false ?

Comment: Do you mean p Sylow for first one?

Comment: No, that  is for $n$ @ChinnapparajR

Comment: What is an $n$-Sylow when $n$ isn't prime?

Comment: @user10354138  ok   $n$ is  prime

Comment: Why are you dividing by $(p-1)^n$?  Try $n=2$ and some odd prime $p$, for example.

Comment: @user10354138 wait let me  calculate

Comment: @user10354138  i got $p+1 $ for  $n = 2$

Comment: So you are claiming, for example, that the order of a $2$-Sylow in $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_5)$ is $6$.  Is this possible?

Comment: ya   u got my point    @user10354138